# Dynamically Update ScrollView with Instances of Views - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, dynamic, uiscrollview, instance

I'm wondering how you add multiple instances of views with content - to a UIScrollView. A bit like any app with data (e.g. Facebook).

Here is an example of the process i want to achieve below that explains better than what I can write in words:

[image]

Here is the general idea of my array containing data:

```
e.g. Array *data 
{
   [0] = contains my first instance of data i want in scroll view

   [1] = contains my second instance of data i want in my custom view

}
```

The data I have in the Array is local containing all the values I need already.

How are you able to achieve this? Is there any examples/tutorials i could potentially follow on this process.

Comment: Sounds like a `UITableView`.

Comment: Agree with the comment above, you're talking about UITableView

Comment: You may check out [this](http://www.appcoda.com/uitableview-tutorial-storyboard-xcode5/) tutorial about UITableView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a custom UITableView - http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-customize-uitableview-storyboard/ .